# Tell git not to use my GitHub account (Keychain) for public repositories - it's a privacy issue

Tags: password, homebrew, keychain, privacy, git

Whenever some script or Git clones/pulls something from GitHub I don't wish to send my GitHub Account, if the repo is public.

How to make sure I won't be authenticated with my GitHub user with Keychain?

```
> brew search geoip
geoip                                                                                                                                geoipupdate
Error: GitHub
The GitHub credentials in the macOS keychain may be invalid.
Clear them with:
  printf "protocol=https\nhost=github.com\n" | git credential-osxkeychain erase
Or create a personal access token:
  https://github.com/settings/tokens/new?scopes=gist,public_repo&description=Homebrew
and then set the token as: export HOMEBREW_GITHUB_API_TOKEN="your_new_token"

> git credential-osxkeychain erase
host=github.com
protocol=https
```

Answer (score 8):

Add the variable `HOMEBREW_NO_GITHUB_API` to your environment.

For example add this to your `.bash_profile` to turn off "once for all":

```
export HOMEBREW_NO_GITHUB_API=1
```

or put it in front of the `brew` for single actions:

```
HOMEBREW_NO_GITHUB_API=1 brew search geoip
```

Comment: thanks @techraf but I search for a general solution, not only Homebrew